# Validating phone number in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

please i created this function for mail and phone number validation, the mail own works, bt the phone own does nt work.

```
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$",     
         trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

if(trim($_POST['phonenumber']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/$",      
          trim($_POST['phonenumber']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $phonenumber= trim($_POST['phonenumber']);
}
```

Comment: Is it the trailing `$/$'? Try changing it to just `$` and see if that works....

Comment: `ereg` functions are deprecated. See [`preg`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php). Also, please clearly define what a valid phone number is.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be using `preg_match` instead of `eregi`.

Aside from that, people enter phone numbers in a variety of ways. The easiest way to handle them is to strip out anything that isn't a digit, and see if you have ten digits:

```
$number = preg_replace("/\D/","",$_POST['phonenumber']);
if( strlen($number) == 10) { /* ok */ }
else { /* error */ }
```

Comment: `+972 52 1234567` is a valid phone number.

Comment: True, but I was assuming the question was only accepting US phone numbers, owing the lack of any attempt to handle country codes.

Comment: i do want it to accept all numbers

Comment: In that case, just strip out anything that isn't a digit. After all, you can't type anything but digits into a phone's keypad.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do it would be to strip all non-numeric characters from the input and check that the length is within a certain range. Especially if you're storing this data in a database so you don't end up storing unnecessary data.

You might want to leave the `x` character in if you want to allow extensions. Here's a function to remove all non-digit characters from a string (except `x`).

```
function removeNonNumeric($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^\dx]/', '', $string)
}
```

When you need to output the result, you can format it however you want.